# Cant `make install` ovs

Tags: ubuntu, makefile, debian, openvswitch, dpdk

I am following [this](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/INSTALL.DPDK.md) guide to install OVS with DPDK.

I manage till **2.3 Install OVS**

```
 cd $OVS_DIR
 ./boot.sh
 ./configure --with-dpdk=$DPDK_BUILD
```

all runs fine without any error but when I do

```
make install
```

It fails.

Here's the output

```
root@ubuntu:/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0# make install
make  install-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0'
Making install in datapath
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0/datapath'
make[3]: Entering directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0/datapath'
make[4]: Entering directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0/datapath'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0/datapath'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0/datapath'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0/datapath'
make[2]: Entering directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0'
depbase=`echo lib/netdev-dpdk.lo | sed 's|[^/]*$|.deps/&|;s|\.lo$||'`;\
/bin/bash ./libtool  --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -I ./include -I ./include -I ./lib -I ./lib -I/usr/include   -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-arith -Wformat-security -Wswitch-enum -Wunused-parameter -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -mssse3 -I/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64  -g -O2 -MT lib/netdev-dpdk.lo -MD -MP -MF $depbase.Tpo -c -o lib/netdev-dpdk.lo lib/netdev-dpdk.c &&\
mv -f $depbase.Tpo $depbase.Plo
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I ./include -I ./include -I ./lib -I ./lib -I/usr/include -Wstrict-prototypes -Wall -Wextra -Wno-sign-compare -Wpointer-arith -Wformat-security -Wswitch-enum -Wunused-parameter -Wbad-function-cast -Wcast-align -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-field-initializers -fno-strict-aliasing -mssse3 -I/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -g -O2 -MT lib/netdev-dpdk.lo -MD -MP -MF lib/.deps/netdev-dpdk.Tpo -c lib/netdev-dpdk.c -o lib/netdev-dpdk.o
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘__rte_pktmbuf_init’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:293:5: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘RTE_MBUF_ASSERT’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     RTE_MBUF_ASSERT(mp->elt_size >= sizeof(struct dp_packet));
     ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘netdev_dpdk_vhost_user_construct’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:708:11: error: too few arguments to function ‘rte_vhost_driver_register’
     err = rte_vhost_driver_register(netdev->vhost_id);
           ^
In file included from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:56:0:
/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_virtio_net.h:95:5: note: declared here
 int rte_vhost_driver_register(const char *path, uint64_t flags);
     ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘is_vhost_running’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:995:32: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct virtio_net’
     return (dev != NULL && (dev->flags & VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING));
                                ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:995:42: error: ‘VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     return (dev != NULL && (dev->flags & VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING));
                                          ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:995:42: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘netdev_dpdk_vhost_rxq_recv’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1049:37: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rte_vhost_dequeue_burst’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
     nb_rx = rte_vhost_dequeue_burst(virtio_dev, qid * VIRTIO_QNUM + VIRTIO_TXQ,
                                     ^
In file included from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:56:0:
/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_virtio_net.h:194:10: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct virtio_net *’
 uint16_t rte_vhost_dequeue_burst(int vid, uint16_t queue_id,
          ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘__netdev_dpdk_vhost_send’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1138:43: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rte_vhost_enqueue_burst’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         tx_pkts = rte_vhost_enqueue_burst(virtio_dev, vhost_qid,
                                           ^
In file included from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:56:0:
/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_virtio_net.h:174:10: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct virtio_net *’
 uint16_t rte_vhost_enqueue_burst(int vid, uint16_t queue_id,
          ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1157:21: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘rte_vring_available_entries’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
             while (!rte_vring_available_entries(virtio_dev, vhost_qid)) {
                     ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘netdev_dpdk_get_stats’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1526:33: error: ‘struct rte_eth_stats’ has no member named ‘imcasts’
     stats->multicast = rte_stats.imcasts;
                                 ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘netdev_dpdk_get_features’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1569:29: error: ‘ETH_LINK_AUTONEG_DUPLEX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
     if (link.link_duplex == ETH_LINK_AUTONEG_DUPLEX) {
                             ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1574:32: error: ‘ETH_LINK_SPEED_10’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if (link.link_speed == ETH_LINK_SPEED_10) {
                                ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1577:32: error: ‘ETH_LINK_SPEED_100’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if (link.link_speed == ETH_LINK_SPEED_100) {
                                ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1580:32: error: ‘ETH_LINK_SPEED_1000’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if (link.link_speed == ETH_LINK_SPEED_1000) {
                                ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1593:32: error: ‘ETH_LINK_SPEED_10000’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if (link.link_speed == ETH_LINK_SPEED_10000) {
                                ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘set_irq_status’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1825:45: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rte_vhost_enable_guest_notification’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         rte_vhost_enable_guest_notification(dev, idx + VIRTIO_RXQ, 0);
                                             ^
In file included from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:56:0:
/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_virtio_net.h:89:5: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct virtio_net *’
 int rte_vhost_enable_guest_notification(int vid, uint16_t queue_id, int enable);
     ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1826:45: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘rte_vhost_enable_guest_notification’ makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
         rte_vhost_enable_guest_notification(dev, idx + VIRTIO_TXQ, 0);
                                             ^
In file included from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:56:0:
/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_virtio_net.h:89:5: note: expected ‘int’ but argument is of type ‘struct virtio_net *’
 int rte_vhost_enable_guest_notification(int vid, uint16_t queue_id, int enable);
     ^
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:630:0,
                 from ./lib/string.h:20,
                 from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:19:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘new_device’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1906:52: error: ‘IF_NAME_SZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if (strncmp(dev->ifname, netdev->vhost_id, IF_NAME_SZ) == 0) {
                                                    ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1915:27: error: ‘VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             dev->flags |= VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING;
                           ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘destroy_device’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1953:16: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘volatile struct virtio_net’
             dev->flags &= ~VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING;
                ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1953:28: error: ‘VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING’ undeclared (first use in this function)
             dev->flags &= ~VIRTIO_DEV_RUNNING;
                            ^
In file included from /usr/include/string.h:630:0,
                 from ./lib/string.h:20,
                 from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:19:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘vring_state_changed’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:1996:55: error: ‘IF_NAME_SZ’ undeclared (first use in this function)
         if (strncmp(dev->ifname, vhost_dev->vhost_id, IF_NAME_SZ) == 0) {
                                                       ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: At top level:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:2036:20: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     .new_device =  new_device,
                    ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:2036:20: note: (near initialization for ‘virtio_net_device_ops.new_device’)
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:2037:23: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     .destroy_device = destroy_device,
                       ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:2037:23: note: (near initialization for ‘virtio_net_device_ops.destroy_device’)
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:2038:28: warning: initialization from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     .vring_state_changed = vring_state_changed
                            ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:2038:28: note: (near initialization for ‘virtio_net_device_ops.vring_state_changed’)
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘dpdk_vhost_cuse_class_init’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:2069:11: error: too few arguments to function ‘rte_vhost_driver_register’
     err = rte_vhost_driver_register(cuse_dev_name);
           ^
In file included from lib/netdev-dpdk.c:56:0:
/usr/src/dpdk-16.07/x86_64-native-linuxapp-gcc/include/rte_virtio_net.h:95:5: note: declared here
 int rte_vhost_driver_register(const char *path, uint64_t flags);
     ^
lib/netdev-dpdk.c: In function ‘is_vhost_running’:
lib/netdev-dpdk.c:996:1: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
 }
 ^
Makefile:4027: recipe for target 'lib/netdev-dpdk.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/netdev-dpdk.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0'
Makefile:4679: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/openvswitch-2.5.0'
Makefile:4985: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

I dont understand what am I missing.
DPDK is `dpdk-16.07`
OpenVSwitch is `openvswitch-2.5.0`
Ubuntu is `Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS`

Any help will be appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: `lib/netdev-dpdk.c:708:11: error: too few arguments to function ‘rte_vhost_driver_register’` This is an error which fails the make.

Comment: @Nagri :  Did you able to solve the issue? If so, can you please post in answer for what you did ? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @ghost204nit I gave up on DPDK and started using OVS as it comes by default. As the answer by Alec Istomin suggest Its the Version issue. I'll just wait for a stable support in the next release maybe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OVS-2.5.0 doesn't support dpdk-16.07.
Use the OVS master newer than commit [netdev-dpdk: Add support for DPDK 16.07](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/commit/0a0f39df1d5ae80bb905cffa8a011356e4193d9a) from August 3rd. This commit adds support of dpdk-16.07 to OVS.

Answer (score 1):

It fails because OVS2.5 "stable release" doesn't support dpdk 16.07 (only support dpdk2.1). You can confirm dpdk version support in the downloaded directory file INSTALL.DPDK.md.

That being said, you can run ovs2.5 with dpdk16.07 by using "current development of ovs" option in the doc, instead of "stable release" option.

So, in [this](https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs/blob/master/INSTALL.DPDK.md) doc, **skip following option**:

*OVS stable releases can be downloaded in compressed format from Download OVS

cd /usr/src

wget http://openvswitch.org/releases/openvswitch-.tar.gz

tar -zxvf openvswitch-.tar.gz

export OVS_DIR=/usr/src/openvswitch-*

**Do this**:

*OVS current development can be clone using 'git' tool

cd /usr/src/

git clone https://github.com/openvswitch/ovs.git

export OVS_DIR=/usr/src/ovs*

Error will be resolved !!